# react component doesnt rerender when params from router change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i have a route like `<Route path='/video/:id' element={<Component/>} />` and in this component i set a `videoId` state for `params.id`.

But when i'm in `/video/asdya123` and click a element with negative hook to direct to another url like `/video/di1h122` its doesn't rerender.

```
const [videoId, setVideoId] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (type === 'video') setVideoId(params.videoId);
  if (type === 'playlist') setVideoId(playlistItems.contents[playlistIndex].video.videoId);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   fetching something here
}, [videoId]);  if (videoId) {
```

anyway to make it rerender when the url changing

Comment: You probably need to add `params` in the first `useEffect`'s dependencies

Comment: it works when i moved the things inside useEffect to useState

Comment: oh adding params in dependencies works too

Answer (score -1):

It is an expected behavior. Only the value has been changed but the route has not been changed so the re-render does not happen.

To get the desired behavior, you can use **key** props on component as

```
<Component {...props} key={Math.random()} />
```

Every time the params change the key props changes which results the re-render.

Comment: The proposed solution is a hack and will affect performance.

Comment: yes, but it works. And the performance, it works fine unless you have 1000s of re-render in same page

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hack as hacks are generally just a hacky way to do a *correct-ish* thing. This is just a complete anti-pattern.